# Writing binary files in C++

Tags: c++, binary

I have a device which sends me binary data of type uint32_t. I want to save the data to a binary file. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ofstream myFile ("data2.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

   bool buffer[32];

   for (int k = 0; k<100; k++)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i<32;i++) 
   {
     buffer[i] = (bool)rand()%2;
   }
   myFile.write ((char*)&buffer, 32);
  }
   myFile.close();
}
```

It works, but the size of the file is 3.2 kB, not 0.4 kB. Moreover, when I try to read the data from the file (the data produced by my device), I get strange outcome, not in the format described in the manual. Of course, there is more data than I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're writing 100 times 32 bytes.  Why do you think it should be 0.4kB?  Am I missing something?  --- Oh, I see...

Comment: 32 bools is 32 bytes normally.  unit32 is a 32 bit data type that is 4 bytes at an 8 bit byte.

Comment: So, what's the safest way to write uint_32t to a binary file?

Comment: You didn't tell us what format you expected.

Comment: _"As far as I know binary files use one bit for each boolean variable"_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: You know you could save time by checking `RAND_MAX` and then just writing the results of `rand()` directly ~100 times right?

Comment: Side Note: Only some stupid operating systems recognize ' ios::binary' - other ignore it.

Answer (score 9):

A `bool` takes one byte.  Check `sizeof(bool)` and you'll find it equal to 1.  So the array is 32 bytes long and you're writing it 100 times, therefore 3.2kB.

If you want to store a bit array, you need to use something different from an array of `bool`.  You have a number of options:

1. Use an array of bytes, integers, or anything whose size you know, and explicitly turn on the bits that you want.  Then, store the array.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <cstdint>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
     ofstream myFile ("data2.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

     uint32_t buffer;

     for (int k = 0; k<100; k++) {
       buffer = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i<32; i++) {
         buffer <<= 1;
         buffer |= (bool)(rand()%2);
       }
       myFile.write((char*) &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
     }
     myFile.close();
     return 0;
   }
   ```

   In fact, if you already have an array of `uint32_t` to begin with, then you don't need the loop and you can just store the array directly.  Use the exact `myFile.write` line above, where `buffer` is your `uint32_t` array.
2. Use a `vector<bool>` or preferably a `bitset`.  Both are optimized and use one bit per element.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <bitset>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
     ofstream myFile ("data2.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

     bitset<32> buffer;

     for (int k = 0; k<100; k++) {
       for (int i = 0; i<32; i++) {
         buffer[i] = (bool)(rand()%2);
       }
       myFile.write((char*) &buffer, 32/8);
     }
     myFile.close();
     return 0;
   }
   ```

Of course, in both cases, you output bytes to your file.  In the second case, the number of bits has to be a multiple of 8.